# How to get bytes of any file in Angular 9, store it in an object and post it to a WebAPI controller?

Tags: .net, angular, webapi

I would like to know if it's possible to select multiple files and store each bytes of each file into a list of objects and send it to a .net webapi controller? I've been searching examples of that but I did not find any. I would appreciate if you can help. Thank you!!

Comment: Why are you using Angular 9?

Comment: Use a `HTMLInputElement` with `type = 'file'` and `multiple = true` to prompt the user to fill the `files` collection, then create a `FormData` (for `multipart/form-data` POST requests) and load each JS `File`  object and use Angular's `HttpClient` to POST it to an ASP.NET Controller that is configured to accept `multipart/form-data` requests. (Fortheloveofgod **do not** use Base64 encoding to send large files).

Comment: It's was not my decision to use Angular 9, I'm working in a third party project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your array of files by using `<form>` with `<input type="file"...>` with `multiple="multiple"` to select more than one file:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" name="filefield" multiple="multiple" (change)="fileChanged($event.target.files)">
</form>
```

and in your .ts:

```
export class MyClass {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    async fileChanged(filesList: FileList) {
        const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        
        for (let i = 0; i < filesList.length; i++) {
            const fileToUpload = filesList.item(i);
            formData.append(`file${i}`, fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
        }
    
        // submit the form or send it using httpClient
        this.http.post('/api_url', formData);
    }
}
```

If you're looking to read the files and build the http request body manually (not using `<form>` with `<input type="file"...>` elements, you can use this function:

```
function getBase64(file: File) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (!file) {
            reject('file object is null');
    }

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onloadend = function () {
            resolve({ res: reader.result, name: file.name });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}
```

But, this is not advised.